# What is the 2000 civic SIR coolant temperature sensor thread size?

Tags: honda, civic, coolant

I'm installing an Auto Meter water temp gauge and didn't receive an adapter with it. Anyone know the thread size of the stock coolant temp sender on a B16A2 engine? (Single wire)... I was going to do a T fitting on the upper rad hose, but I can't find a 1.25 T fitting with a -27 NPT top.

You can't splice into stock wire because values are different and it will ground out. I've been searching everywhere to no avail.

Answer (score 1):

I **hate** dealing with adding aftermarket parts and dealing with sizes.

Here's the replacement [Duralast Coolant Temperature Sensor](http://www.autozone.com/engine-management/coolant-temperature-sensor/duralast-coolant-temperature-sensor/honda/civic-si/2000/4-cylinders-1-6l-mfi-vtec-dohc/78826_0_18589/) for your vehicle and engine.  In the description, it says it's thread is **`M12 x 1.5 Thread`**.  The ValuCraft brand version agrees about the size.

Good luck!